# How to pass a json object as a query in a get request

Tags: json, google-apps-script, get-request

I am trying to pass parameters to a url get request that requires one of the parameters be a json object. I am using Google apps script. I get an invalid argument exception. The searchConditions parameter requires the json. I also need to pass some additional parameters after the query to specify the fields to return.

The example in the documentation looks like this:

```
https://theurl/search?searchConditions=[{ "Param1": "value", "Param2": "value"}]&fields=[ "Field1", "Field2", "etc"]
```

My code is as follows:

```
var url = "https:/theurl/search?searchConditions=";

var conditions = {
  "Param1":"value",
  "Param2":"value"
  };
  
var fields = "&fields=[\'Field1\',\'Field2\',\'etc\']";

var options = {
  "method":"Get",
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "muteHttpExceptions" : true
    };
   options.headers = {"Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxx="};

   var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + conditions + fields, options);
   var data = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText())
```

Update: From Documentation:

Search Incidents

URI
https://trackerbeyond.phaseware.com:443/pro9/api/incident/search

HTTP Verb
GET

Request Parameters
There are two request parameters to pass in as part of the URI; searchConditions and fields.

searchConditions Parameter
This is an array of search conditions. Note that when multiple conditions are defined, all conditions must be met for the Incident to be returned.

This table shows the fields to set within each search condition.
Fieldname   Description
ConditionType   Possible values: Exact, BeginsWith, Contains, DateRange, IsBlank, IsNotBlank, ArchiveStatus, OpenCloseStatus.
FieldName   The name of the field to search against. To get the full list of fields use the Incident Schema API call.
TableName   The name of the table that the field exists on. Possible values are z_Incident, UserIncident, z_FullTextMain, Customer, UserCustomer, Contacts ,UserContacts ,CustomerContacts ,UserCustomerContacts ,CustomerProducts, CustomerSupportPackages ,IncidentParts ,IncidentParties ,DepartmentGroupingMembers (for searching on a DepartmentGrouping). If blank then z_Incident will be used.
Note: For the CreateDate and Description fields use z_FullTextMain for the TableName.
Lookup  An object that contains two fields; LookupTableName and LookupFieldName.
SearchValue The value to search on.
EndingSearchValue   Used when specifying ConditionType of DateRange to supply the ending date.
OpenActive  Possible values: All, OpenOrActive, ClosedOrArchived. Please note that this parameter only applies when adding a search condition with ConditionType of OpenCloseStatus.

Example
In this example, the first search condition is for searching on DepartmentID equal to 1. The second condition is for searching on Priority description of "Priority 3". This is an example of using the Lookup field to search on a description for a lookup instead of the id. The third condition is for including both open and closed incidents. By default only open incidents are returned.
[
{
"ConditionType": "Exact",
"FieldName": "DepartmentID",
"TableName": "",
"Lookup": "",
"SearchValue": "1",
"EndingSearchValue": "",
"OpenActive": "OpenOrActive"
},
{
"ConditionType": "Exact",
"FieldName": "PriorityID",
"TableName": "",
"Lookup": {
"LookupTableName": "LU_Priority",
"LookupFieldName": "Description"
},
"SearchValue": "Priority 3",
"EndingSearchValue": "",
"OpenActive": "OpenOrActive"
},
{
"ConditionType": "OpenCloseStatus",
"FieldName": "",
"TableName": "",
"Lookup": "",
"SearchValue": "1",
"EndingSearchValue": "",
"OpenActive": "All"
}
]

fields Parameter
This is an array of fields to return in the result. If this parameter is left blank then a default set of fields will be returned.

Successful call made from the Test this API interface: [https://trackerbeyond.phaseware.com:443/pro9/api/incident/search?searchConditions=[](https://trackerbeyond.phaseware.com:443/pro9/api/incident/search?searchConditions=%5B) { "ConditionType": "Exact", "FieldName": "StatusID", "SearchValue": "12", "OpenActive": "OpenOrActive" } ]&fields=[ "CustomerName", "CreateDate", "AgentFullName", "ClosedDateTime", "StatusID", "IncidentID", "Description" ]

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am successfully making API calls to that url. Here is the documentation and a sample of the call. The sample was taken from a "Test this API" interface in the documentation. It runs successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- At GET method, `contentType` is not required to be used.
- When you want to use `Accept`, please include it in the request header.
- Although I'm not sure about the detail of the specification of the API you want to use, from `The example in the documentation looks like this: https://theurl/search?searchConditions=[{ "Param1": "value", "Param2": "value"}]&fields=[ "Field1", "Field2", "etc"]` in your question, I think that in this case, how about URL encoding the values of query parameter?

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
var url = "https:/theurl/search";
var conditions = [{ "Param1": "value", "Param2": "value" }];
var fields = ["Field1", "Field2", "etc"];
var options = {
  "method": "get",
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxx=",
    "Accept": "application/json",
  },
  "muteHttpExceptions": true
};
var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${url}?searchConditions=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(conditions))}&fields=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(fields))}`, options);
var data = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText())
```

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that the URL of `https:/theurl/search` and the token of `"Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxx="` can be used for the API you want to use. Please be careful this.
- If above modification didn't resolve your issue, can you provide the official document of the API you want to use? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### References:

- [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)